# F# Add New Item to Collections.Map?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I want to create a map and a function to add item to that map.

This is what I did

```
let mymap = Map.empty

let myfunc nId nValue = 
    mymap = Map.add nId nValue ;;
```

But this produced following Error
`This expression was expected to have type Map<'a,'b> but here has type Map<'c,'d> -> Map<'c,'d>`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from assigning `mymap` to a new value as in John's answer, you can do it using a more idiomatic FP way:

```
let mymap = Map.empty

let myfunc nId nValue = 
    Map.add nId nValue mymap
```

Where John's `myfunc` has a signature of `'a -> 'b -> unit` because of the assignment, mine has a signature of `'a -> 'b -> Map<'a, 'b>`, which is more common in FP to return a new `Map` instead of modifying an existing map (`mymap`).

Comment: Does this mean I have to create new variable to store new table everytime I alter the items?

Comment: @MichaelO.Y., yes it does. But this is considered more idiomatic in F# or functional programming in general, which is to avoid side effect.

Answer (score 9):

Maps are immutable so you need to do `let mutable mymap`.

Also, `=` does comparison, you need `<-` for assignment, which is why you got the error.

Something like

```
let mutable mymap = Map.empty

let myfunc nId nValue = 
    mymap <- Map.add nId nValue mymap;;
```

is what you want